# Посчитать количество отэксплойденных значений

Tags: php

Нужно посчитать сколько значений в строке $prefa. Код ниже не работает.

```
$prefa = '0|1|308';
$pref = explode('|', $prefa);
$ai = 0;
while($rowa = $pref) {
$ai++;
}
echo $ai;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь, конечно, сказывается отсутствие программистского бэкграунда у большинства пользователей РНР.
Потому что программист, даже такой, который изучал только информатику в школе, знает, что "отэксплойденные знанеия" называются "*массив*", а для подсчета элементов в массиве в любом языке есть функция, которая обычно называется `count()`.

Ну а с кодом проблема в том, что оператор `while` не перебирает массив сам по себе. `while` - это всего лишь некое подобие `if`-а, он просто проверяет условие. А чтобы `while` перебрал массив, надо внутрь добавить какой-нибудь код для перебора. Например:

```
$prefa = '0|1|308';
$pref = explode('|', $prefa);
$count = 0;
while($rowa = each($pref)) {
    $count++;
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: Ну что Вы так грубо? Я бы тоже хотел открутить йайца неучу, но вместо этого несу добро и знания!

Comment: с explode в первый раз столкнулся. не вдумывался даже что он возвращает

Comment: @Rufex, Т.е. ты начал использовать неизвестную тебе функцию, после того, как ты не понял как она работает, ты полез не в документацию, а на форум?
Жесть, чувак.

Comment: "...это всего лишь некое подобие if-а" @Shorty, существует предельно понятное название такого цикла - [циклы с предусловием](https://goo.gl/c0U9L9).

Answer (score 2):

Хм, зачем такие сложности?
`explode` возвращает массив, значит просто узнаём количество элементов в нём:

```
$prefa = '0|1|308';
$pref = explode('|', $prefa);
$count = count($pref); // 3
```